# Screen Resolution is reduced and cannot be reverted

Tags: windows-7, monitor, screen-resolution, vga

I have a laptop(Sony Vaio VPCSA9e) (OS: Windows 7) and a monitor (LG W1945S). I used to connect the monitor to my laptop in 1440X900 screen resolution without any problem. (I connect it via VGA cable.)

But, somehow, when I now connect the monitor, the screen resolution is 1024X768 and I cannot change. I also recognized that "Device on VGA" is selected for display option instead of W1945 as before.

There are some problems similar to mine in the Internet and I have:

1) Updated graphics drivers

2) Updated monitor driver (I ensured that default screen resolution is 1440X900 in .ink file)

3) Tried with another VGA cable.

However, none of them didn't work. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: This should be at superuser.com, not here.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I solved the problem. It is due to VGA cable as pointed out prior questions. I was unlucky because my second VGA cable did not work. Bingo in third!